# Wrapping overlay hover text over an Image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to wrap my text to ensure it fits within the boundaries of my images and their hover overlay however what I have tried so far, including centreing, still does not show the entire text.

Below is the CSS and HTML

```css
.hoverimg {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.hoverimg:hover .overlay {
  width: 70%;
}

.overlaytxt {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="hoverimg"><img alt="The Engineer" class="image" src="/drupal/sites/default/files/inline-images/CE_0.png" />
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="overlaytxt">Garry "Big Gaz" Oldman is our Chief Engineering officer and leader of the fleet, he ensures all of the moving vehicles are perfect for our needs</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you want the text to do if it is too large to fit on the image?

Comment: We'll get to that bridge when I cross it PETE

Comment: you want the text to fit on the same line?

Comment: No I would like it to be wrapped across the images area

Comment: remove white-space:nowrap

Comment: @godfather Thank you so much , now what if the text was too big for the image (Just thinking about contingency) how would I get it to fit the image?

Comment: check my answer if it helped plz accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove white-space:nowrap and text-align:center and you can use the font-size vw

```css
.hoverimg {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.hoverimg:hover .overlay {
  width: 70%;
}

.overlaytxt {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

 
}
```

```html
<div class="hoverimg"><img alt="The Engineer" class="image" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg" />
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="overlaytxt">Garry "Big Gaz" Oldman is our Chief Engineering officer and leader of the fleet, he ensures all of the moving vehicles are perfect for our needs</div>
  </div>
</div>
```